# Get control name of check boxes in checklistbox?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to get **name** of the checkboxes in checkedlistbox control.

By this following code I am only able to get the Text associated with the checkboxes :

```
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim CheckedList =
        (
          From Item In clbCheckedListBox.Items.Cast(Of String)() _
          .Where(Function(xItem, Index) clbCheckedListBox.GetItemChecked(Index))
          Select Item
        ).ToList
```

> Example:  I want **chk_01** instead of **Hello World**  
>       (checklistbox name = **clbCheckedListBox**
>       One of the checkbox name = **chk_01**
>       **chk_01** checkbox contains text **Hello World**
>   )

P.s. : I am getting Text of only **checked** checkboxes by the above code
(I want same but with the checkbox **Name**)

Please Help...Thanks In Advance..

Comment: It feels like WinForms, but the CheckedListBox control doesn't have a name for each checkable item.  Can you set me straight?

Comment: You are right @LarsTech . . .How to get Index / id (somthing that is permanent )

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can refer to the `clbCheckedListBox.ID` property to get the unique id of a control.

There also the UniqueID property and TagName that could interest you.

The fact that you `.Cast(Of String)()` might be a problem here has it would require the full cehckbox object to perform what is am suggesting

Comment: I think you cast the selected checkboxes into string instead of check box?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim CheckedList =
        (
            From Name In clbCheckedListBox.CheckedIndices.Cast(Of Integer)() _
            .Where(Function(xItem, Index) clbCheckedListBox.GetItemChecked(Index))
            Select Name
        ).ToList
```

The Change Is:
**clbCheckedListBox.CheckedIndices.Cast(Of Integer)**

Answer (score 0):

> One of the checkbox name = chk_01

This doesn't make any sense since there is no Name property for the CheckedListBox.Item.  The only way to identify them is by the text or the index

Something like this will return a list of the text of very item that is checked:

```
Dim CheckedList = (From Text In clbCheckedListBox.CheckedItems() Select Text).ToList
```

Or alternatively you could get a list of the indexes that are checked like this:

```
Dim CheckedList = (From Index In clbCheckedListBox.CheckedIndices() _
                   Select Index).ToList
```